# Issue with synapse workspace creation

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvQGu.png)

Above is the screenshot for the error.
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/xyz/resourceGroups/iam/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Azure.SynapseAnalytics","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ReachedPerSubscriptionWorkspaceLimit","message":"Reached the maximum number of Synapse workspaces allowed for this subscription. Please contact Microsoft support to request an exception. Subscription: xyz Subscription offer type: AzureForStudents_2018-01-01. Current maximum: 0."}]}

Tried to re-register the Synapse workspace but still have the same issue as I do not have a single workspace created for Synapse.
My account is a student subscription account.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've reached the maximum number of Synapse workspaces allowed for your subscription, and it mentions that the current maximum is 0.
I suggest you you reach the azure support and req for quota increase. You can do this through the Azure Portal or Azure Support website. Explain the situation, provide them with the error message, and mention that you're using an Azure for Students subscription.
I will provide the link for the [page fill the info and the support team will assist you,

https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/NewSupportRequestV3Blade/callerWorkflowId/d2cd6f09-a6e1-4ea7-959b-3a802b8ae5df/callerName/Microsoft_Azure_Support%2FHelpAndSupportOverview.ReactView